# Why is my CNN activation maximization split vertically?

Tags: cnn, visualization

I am using this code in Python:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from tf_keras_vis.activation_maximization import ActivationMaximization

def get_conv(in_model):
    target_layer = in_model.get_layer(name="block5_conv3")
    new_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=in_model.inputs, outputs=target_layer.output)
    new_model.layers[-1].activation = tf.keras.activations.linear
    return new_model

def get_score(output):
    outputs = [o[0] for o in output]
    return outputs

model = tf.keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16()
vis = ActivationMaximization(model, get_conv)
seed = tf.random.uniform((1, *model.input.shape[1:]), 0, 255)
maps = vis(get_score, seed)
plt.imshow(maps[0])
plt.show()
```

And this is what I get:

[image]

I was wondering why there is a huge flat image region in the bottom half of the image.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering this myself as it may be helpful to others.

The error is in this line:

```py
outputs = [o[0] for o in output]
```

I had copied and pasted this from dense-layer visualization code, where it is correct, selecting class 0 for visualization. Here, it is not *wrong*, but what it does is select the top row of that conv layer across all filters (and not the first filter of that layer). Hence the many small-scale features near the top row, more large-scale features near the middle, and nothing more near the bottom. I believe this may nicely visualize the perceptive field of the network.

For the record,

```py
outputs = [o[:, :, 0] for o in output]
```

yields expected output.